# How to generate icons with cordova-res in Capacitor

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-vue

I am following [this doc](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/splash-screens-and-icons) to generate app icons using cordova-res. When I run `cordova-res android --skip-config --copy` it generates android icons in resources folder. The doc says

> Next, run the following to generate all images then copy them into the
> native projects

Its unclear if the command does the copying or do I have to manually copy the icons into native project. After using the command I don't see any git changes in Android platform folder. I did another build, the installed app still shows default Capacitor logo

If I have to manually copy them over, where do I put these generated images if the Android folder is created with Capacitor?

Comment: I managed to get it working using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61740040/616221)

Answer (score -1):

if you add the `--copy` flag, `cordova-res` will copy the resources to the correct folder which is what you have done, so yes, it will copy the generated files.

Comment: I did that but its not working. I ended up using this script  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61740040/616221