# Ionic/Angular cant see images in real phone

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, multidimensional-array, ionic4

I have a project about the film-tv series list. But photos isn't seenable in the real phone. I can see it in an emulator or ionic lab but I can't see it on my real phone.

```
 <img style="margin-left: 5%; border-radius: 15px;"  src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500{{item.poster_path}}" height="250px" width="250px"  >
```

It's my code about img. When I use it like that I can see on an emulator  like: https://prnt.sc/12jdedl

But when I open it from my phone its shows like: https://prnt.sc/12jddef  how can I fix it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you view a web inspector on your mobile phone (via usb cable)? You can get more information about what's going wrong.

Comment: @JohnTyner i just sent to android studio then connect my phone via usb cable then open my app but cant see anything. How can i open web inspector while i am in my apk ?

Comment: @JohnTyner ı checked from my computer its all looks fine. That source URL is right too when i open that url from my phone manually i can see that image from google but with program i dont know why its not showing

Comment: You can use Chrome to inspect `chrome://inspect/#devices` - I would look to see if it was being reported as a 404 (file not found in the network tab) - or perhaps ionic/angular is blocking the image (would show up in the errors tab).

Comment: @JohnTyner Thank you ! I tried it and i can see photos now with chrome inspect. But when i open my apk file i still cant see . Its so odd i cant understand why

Comment: What I am suggesting is to run the app on your phone - using the deployed APK file. Then plug the phone into the computer, mount the device using inspect/#devices - and then look at the inspector. If the image is a 404 somehow the wrong data is going to the `<img>` tag. Also, make sure you're using @DavidB recommendation below.

Comment: @JohnTyner I finally found error code. Its saying : ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: @JohnTyner I tried his recommendation too but it didnt work becouse of that error i guess. After i fix it it will work im so sure

Comment: @UğurcanUçar Just want to clarify, are you using Cordova or Capacitor? `ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED` showing up because webview doesn't allow plain http protocol. You simple fix it by using `https` URL protocol, or opt-out [cleartext traffic](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is: `ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED`

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67127207/1772933

First, create the Network Security Config file here YOUR_IONIC_APP_ROOT\android\app\main\res\xml\network_security_config.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
   <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>www.example.com</domain>
   </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Then edit YOUR_IONIC_APP_ROOT\android\app\main\AndroidManifest.xml adding android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" to application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.ionic.starter">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!-- ... -->
    </application>
    <!-- ... -->
</manifest>
```

Comment: I dont have resources folder on my visual code . I saw that folder from few videos but in mine i dont have that

Comment: I changed my answer - try it out

Comment: @JohnTyler I wish i can do but i dont have enough reputation for now. But when i have it i will do it!

Comment: @UğurcanUçar If you're using Cordova then you need to generate it by using `ionic cordova resources`. If you're using Capacitor then follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61740040/7401054)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your curly brackets `{{...}}` sit in the middle of the `src` string. They don't have a string interpolation feature. In order to combine two strings in the angular template you may try this:

```
 <img style="margin-left: 5%; border-radius: 15px;"  [src]="'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + item.poster_path" height="250px" width="250px"  >
```

Comment: B Thank you for your answer. But its still same result. In emulator i can see images but on my device i still cant see that photos.

Comment: when you are free can you help me again brother ? I need your help

Comment: Seems like @John Tyner already found a solution. Some security http or CORS issue would have been my second guess.